# In C++, to use the built-in mutexes, do I also need to use the built-in threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization

In C++, to use the built-in mutexes, do I also need to use the built-in threads (as opposed to managing threads directly via OS calls)?

I haven't tried anything yet, as I'm not sure if all problems would be visible. Any thoughts?

Comment: Broadly speaking, if you're making direct OS calls, you're outside the scope of what the standard guarantees (since portability is already out the window), and you'll need to look at the documentation for your specific toolchain.

Comment: BTW, have you read "Threads Cannot Be Implemented As a Library"? [[PDF](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2004/HPL-2004-209.pdf)] If not, I recommend it; it should give you some insights into why you probably can't mix mutexes from one source with threads from a different source.

Comment: That article was good. Covered a lot.

Comment: The standard says nothing, so it really depends on how the standard library capabilities are implemented.   Practically, the standard library functions/classes will often be some sort of wrapper or facade over internals implemented using OS calls - because that is the easier implementation choice.  Although your risk is low,  it is non-zero since nothing prevents a situation of the OS providing more granular control, and your usage of OS functions *might* break assumptions made in the standard library in subtle ways.

Comment: In practical terms, a tremendous amount of code would break if this didn't work. Consider your C++ code linking to a C library that creates its own threads and then uses callbacks to interact with your C++ code. Or mixing in C++ libs with Boost threads

Answer (score 2):

Like most classes in the C++ Standard Library, C++ mutexes can be used independently from the C++ threading classes.  So yes, you can use OS thread APIs if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Given everything the compiler would need to consider to safely implement synchronization (particularly with the optimizations performed), I think it is probably best for the compiler to know as much about the situation as possible.

Thus, I'll be using both it's mutexes *and* threads.